# How do I make a smaller range with two given integers?

Tags: c++, int, range, integer

For example,

I have a range 14269-14274.

To conserve space on the screen my users want to have it display in the format 14269-74.

Another example would be a range of 14269-14529 which should output as 14269-529.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: `std::string short_range(int a, int b) { /*implementation*/ }` and `std::cout << short_range(x, y);`?

Comment: What do you expect from us, should we write that function for you?

Comment: You will have to convert the numbers to strings and then compare their characters one by one. When you encounter a difference, you output the remaining characters of the second number. There are some special cases to handle (b<a, number of characters is different etc.), but I'm sure you can figure it out ;)

Comment: @SvenS Thanks for the help, worked a treat. Can't believe I didn't think about converting them to strings for comparing. I feel a bit stupid now. Thanks again :D

Comment: @SvenS: you don't HAVE to convert the numbers to strings. (See my answer).

Comment: @SaniHuttunen, please see my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
int a = 14269;
int b = 14529;
int endrange = b % pow(10, floor(log10(b - a) + 1));
```

You need to make sure that a < b though.

Comment: a=999, b=1001; b-a=2; log10(2)~=0.3; floor(0.3+1)=1; pow(10, 1)=10; b%10=1.
I don't think this works for most combinations.

Comment: More specifically: "The number of digits the two numbers differ in" (what we want to know) does not always equal "the number of digits their difference has" (what you calculate here).

Answer (score 1):

You can check the first digit that differs, output the first number and then the second one, starting at the first different digit.

This of course only makes sense if the two numbers have the same length.

Were you expecting the implementation?